# Why my WinXP is showing 1,99 GB ram

Tags: windows-xp, memory

I have 2 GBs of RAM installed and my Windows Xp is showing 1,99 in the properties. Also a dual core intel at 2,20, but the properties shows 1,18..
Any idea? Thanks..

Comment: Related: [One core at 3.2 GHz, one at 3.19 GHz - what's wrong?](http://superuser.com/q/697650/53590)

Answer (score 2):

For the processor... I am not sure - what processor is? Just make sure you haven't been mis-sold something.

For the memory, that is pretty normal... You may have a little being used for shared graphics or it is simply a mismatch - it is really nothing to worry about and you do have 2GB there!

Comment: Intel Core Duo 2 T6600 Code name Penryn @ 2,20, but it's 1,18 in the properties. I'm not worried about the RAM i'm sure it's fine but why the processor is running at this speed? There aren't any clock or overclock settings in my bios..

Comment: Is your machine plugged in whilst looking? It may be automatically underclocking itself to save power.

Comment: Yes it is. It's sony vaio vgn series, forgot to mention.